# why do the DL tag uses all the space even I specify its width?

Tags: html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .headerText {

            color: #8d9096
        }

        dl {
            border: 1px solid #bdc8ca;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }

        dt,
        dd {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-right: 7px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-left: 7px;
            white-space: nowrap
        }

        dd ~ dt,
        dd ~ dd {
        }

        dt {
            color: #8d9096;
            float: left;
            width: 90px;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            text-align: right
        }   

        dd {
            margin-left: 155px;
            border-left: 1px dotted #bdc8ca;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        dd:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<dl style="width: 300px">
    <dt><span> xyz</span></dt>
    <dd><span> xyz2</span></dd>
    <dt><span> xyz3</span></dt>
    <dd><span> xyz4</span></dd>
</dl>

<dl style="width: 300px">
    <dt><span> mno</span></dt>
    <dd><span> mno2</span></dd>
    <dt><span> mno3</span></dt>
    <dd><span> mno4</span></dd>
</dl>

<dl style="width: 300px">
    <dt><span> abc</span></dt>
    <dd><span> abc2</span></dd>
    <dt><span> abc3</span></dt>
    <dd><span> abc4</span></dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using "DL" tags to display 3 parts of information. Each "DL" width is 300px. My client's monitor should be big enough to show in 1 row.

But I found that the "DL" uses all the remaining space. As a result, There is lot of space in the right and they show in 3 rows. I use "inspect" function in browser and found it is the margin of the "DL". But I cannot minimize them to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<dl>` tag is equal to the width you specified (300px) and does **not use** the remaining space.

If you need to line up these tags on one line, set `display: inline-block` for this tag. Like this:

```
dl {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can also **center** these `<dl>` tags for by setting `text-align: center` for the parent. In your case, it's a `<body>` tag.

Run the snippet:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .headerText {

            color: #8d9096
        }

        dl {
            border: 1px solid #bdc8ca;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        dt,
        dd {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-right: 7px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-left: 7px;
            white-space: nowrap
        }

        dd ~ dt,
        dd ~ dd {
        }

        dt {
            color: #8d9096;
            float: left;
            width: 90px;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            text-align: right
        }   

        dd {
            margin-left: 155px;
            border-left: 1px dotted #bdc8ca;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        dd:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<dl style="width: 300px">
    <dt><span> xyz</span></dt>
    <dd><span> xyz2</span></dd>
    <dt><span> xyz3</span></dt>
    <dd><span> xyz4</span></dd>
</dl>

<dl style="width: 300px">
    <dt><span> mno</span></dt>
    <dd><span> mno2</span></dd>
    <dt><span> mno3</span></dt>
    <dd><span> mno4</span></dd>
</dl>

<dl style="width: 300px">
    <dt><span> abc</span></dt>
    <dd><span> abc2</span></dd>
    <dt><span> abc3</span></dt>
    <dd><span> abc4</span></dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look up flex containers instead of using floats.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.headerText {

    color: #8d9096
}

dl {
    border: 1px solid #bdc8ca;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

dt,
dd {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    white-space: nowrap
}

dt {
    color: #8d9096;
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-align: right
}   

dd {
    margin-left: 155px;
    border-left: 1px dotted #bdc8ca;
    background-color: #fff;
}

dd:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <dl style="width: 300px">
      <dt><span> xyz</span></dt>
      <dd><span> xyz2</span></dd>
      <dt><span> xyz3</span></dt>
      <dd><span> xyz4</span></dd>
    </dl>

    <dl style="width: 300px">
      <dt><span> mno</span></dt>
      <dd><span> mno2</span></dd>
      <dt><span> mno3</span></dt>
      <dd><span> mno4</span></dd>
    </dl>

    <dl style="width: 300px">
      <dt><span> abc</span></dt>
      <dd><span> abc2</span></dd>
      <dt><span> abc3</span></dt>
      <dd><span> abc4</span></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`dl` is a block tag. So the tag next to it will always start in a new row. You can change it like this:

```
dl {
  display: inline-block;
}
```